# Why MySQL innodb use next-key lock rather than record lock?

Tags: mysql

In [MySQL innodb's document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html), it's said in the default transaction isolation level "repeatable-read", MySQL will issue a next-key lock when processing "update" and "delete" statements.

I'm confused why it won't use record lock instead of next-key lock since the advantage of next-key lock is it can avoid "phantom reads", but it is permitted in isolation level "repeatable read".

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked

> InnoDB does not remember the exact WHERE condition, but only knows which index ranges were
>   scanned. The locks are normally next-key locks that also block inserts into the “gap” 
>   immediately before the record.

So next-key lock also block inserts into the selected range which record locks wouldn't.